# jquery dom insert and selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I catch events (.click()) on dynamically inserted DOM elements after page load using jquery?

This is how it not! works:

```
   $("#test").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background","#CCCCCC");
   });

   $("#clickme").click(function(){
       $("body").append("<div id=\"test\">My background isn't changeable!</div>");
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d87ckf1k/3/

Comment: Keep in mind that you are adding more divs that have the same IDs. So change them to class! http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/d87ckf1k/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click","#test",function(){
        $(this).css("background","#CCCCCC");
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d87ckf1k/4/

Comment: jup thx! sorry for duplicate :(